# InstallShield - adding configurations to file

Tags: installshield

I'm building a setup project by using InstallShield. The setup file will do the following tasks:

- Install my application to the machine.
- Look for a folder based on a common string (e.g: MySecondApp) because each machine might has different folder name:

  - Laptop1: C:\Program Files\WindowsApp\MySecondApp_1.2.3.4_asdfsjhewrnewj
  - Desktop2: C:\Program Files\WindowsApp\MySecondApp_1.2.3.5_asdfsjhewrnewj
- In this folder, I have a config file named "myconfig.cfg". My setup file will modify this file by adding some new configurations.

Could you let me know how to do this by using InstalledShield?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by writing a C# library and use it in InstallShield for searching and modifying my config file.

Comment: Phuc, could you please post your code - how you modify the config file and how you call the library?